# Как определить в тексте коды эмоджи и заменить на сами эмоджи?

Tags: javascript, json

У меня есть json объект:

```
{
    ":cool:": "",
    ":plak:": "",
    ":angry:": "",
    ":hmm:": ""
}
```

Мне нужно определить в тексте коды эмоджи и потом эти коды заменить на сами эмоджи.

Например, у меня есть текст с кодом эмоджи:

`Привет всем :cool:`

Теперь он должен превратится в эту строку:

`Привет всем`

Как это сделать?

Comment: Пройдитесь по вашему объекту и сделайте `replaceAll` для вашей строки.

Answer (score 0):

> Мне нужно определить в тексте коды эмоджи и потом эти коды заменить на сами эмоджи

Предложу такой вариант замены...

```js
const o = {
  ":cool:": "",
  ":plak:": "",
  ":angry:": "",
  ":hmm:": ""
}
let txt = 'Привет :cool:! Чем бы сегодня заняться :hmm:?'
txt = txt.replace(/:[a-z]+?:/g, k => o[k] ? o[k] : k)
console.log(txt)
```

Comment: Не лучше будет `/:\w+:/g`?

Comment: @ΝNL993, \w Найдет любой словесный (латинский алфавит) символ, включая буквы, цифры и знак подчеркивания. Эквивалентно [A-Za-z0-9_] https://javascript.ru/RegExp Т.ч. встречный вопрос - кому будет лучше?

Comment: `\w Найдет любой ... подчеркивания.` -- это я и без вас знал. `кому будет лучше?` -- мне. Существуют эмодзи числа, а также эмодзи имеющие два в названии слова обычно разделяемые подчёркиванием. Ну а с uppercase буквами и вправду ничего не выходит ‍♂️.